# Were the trumpets in the NT actually shofars?

Tags: revelation, history

This is from [the Jewish Encyclopedia article on "trumpets"](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14530-trumpet):

> In [Shab. 36a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.36a?lang=bi) (comp. [Suk. 34a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.34a?lang=bi)) it is noted that since the destruction of the Temple the names for the shofar and the trumpet had been confused. The same complaint may be made against the Septuagint, which generally renders the Hebrew "shofar" by σάλπιρξ, properly applicable only to the ḥaẓoẓerah, and against the English versions, which render it by "trumpet" or, still more incorrectly, by "cornet." In the Hebrew text the distinction between Shofar and trumpet is well maintained, as may be seen from such passages as Ps. xcviii. 6 and I Chron. xv. 28, where "shofar" and "ḥaẓoẓerah" are mentioned side by side...

These are [all the instances of "shofar" in the Hebrew Names Version](https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=shofar&t=HNV#s=s_primary_0_1). 
These are [all the instances of "trumpet", "trumpets" or "trumpeter" in the Hebrew Names Version](https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=trumpet%20OR%20trumpets%20OR%20trumpeters&t=HNV#s=s_primary_0_1).

[image: Shofars being sounded]

Comment: Until the destruction of the Temple in Jerusalem both the shofar and silver trumpets were used. Silver trumpets were sounded in the Temple by the kohanim during the daily Tanim offerings, and to herald the arrival of Shabbat, Rosh Kodesh (new moon) and the festivals of Sukkot, Pesach and Shavuot. Source: http://www.templeinstitute.org/trumpets-gallery.htm  But what is the connection regarding the trumpets mentioned in Revelation chapter 8? Are you suggesting the angels should be blowing the shofar and that English translators have mistranslated John's words? Sorry to be so slow on the uptake.

Comment: I read the article that I cited and could not be sure but *it sounded to me* like it was saying that both the "LXX" and the English versions exhibit confusion over the identity of the instruments because of the chaos of 70 AD. Is that how you read it?

Comment: Is this "confusion" between the shofar and the trumpet some sort of glaring error in the Old Testament English translations? Or is the "confusion" to do with Revelation chapter 8? It's an interesting question although I don't imagine it matters a toot if the angels blow a shofar or a trumpet.  Everybody will hear it and tremble as the Hebrews did at the foot of Mount Sinai (Exodus 19:13). Still digging for more information. http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13602-shofar

Comment: There are three types of trumpet in the Hebrew. _Chatsoterah_ which stands for natural combat/alarm; _shophar_ which is the trumpet sounding loud at Sinai; and the _yobel_, that which signifies jubilee - liberty and redemption. _Salpigx_ in Greek compares to both the _shophar_ and the _chatsoterah_. The Gospel itself is the _yobel_ of the New Testament. I shall try to enlarge on this in an answer if I am able.

Comment: @NigelJ  Sounds promising, thanks.

Comment: I double posted here:  https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Are-the-trumpets-in-the-Bible-actually-shofars-see-attached-link

Answer (score 2):

This is not an easy question.  The semantics of the language doesn't seem that clear to distinguish the difference in the physical makeup of the instruments. Note the Greek word for trumpet sounds similar to sofar:

[image]

NT words translated trumpet in ESV.

We need more than the language to support this:

[image]

Word translating sofar in the LXX.

So far, I don't see how to get beyond opinion on this question other than archaeology.  Remember even today's common lamp in your home is called a menorah in modern Hebrew.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is pretty clear and simple for those of us who still keep YHWH's Holy Days.

The **silver** trumpets, *Chatsoterah*, of Numbers 10:10, are blown on each of the Seven Holy Days...the yearly ones we are talking about for this question (as opposed to the weekly or monthly holy days such as the seventh-day Sabbath or new moons).

The seven annual holy Appointed Times (*mo'edim*) are detailed in Leviticus 23.

These signify prophetic time periods that were to come starting with the Messiah becoming the Passover Lamb sacrifice. (the First Trumpet)

These yearly Appointed Times we do as in obedience and as a Memorial to observe and be on the lookout for, which is revealed in the Book of Revelation.

The seven trumpets of The Book of Revelation are in fact the time periods in history for the last 2,000 years as they have been unfolding.

We live in the time period known as The Day of Atonement, *Yom Kippur*, or the Sixth Trumpet.

We are awaiting the Seventh Trumpet to blow and Messiah to return and start the Millennial Kingdom, aka, "YHWH The Son" to return to Tabernacle with us again for 1,000+ years. (AKA The **real** Feast of Tabernacles time period that the yearly festival only pointed towards)

(All the yearly holy days are a type and shadow pointing to the real events/time periods in history.)

The seven Appointed Times (holy day celebrations Leviticus 23) are:

1. Passover
2. Feast of Unleavened Bread
3. First Fruits (Wave Sheaf Offering)
4. Pentecost (*Shavuot*) (Feast of Weeks)
5. Day of Trumpets (*Yom Teruah*)
6. Day of Atonement (*Yom Kippur*)
7. Feast of Tabernacles (Feast of Booths) (*Sukkoth*)

Because we blow a silver trumpet on each of these, it is silver trumpets being blown in the Book of Revelation.

In short, the trumpets in Revelation are of the silver type as detailed in Numbers 10.  They call the congregation of Israel together, sound an alarm "*teruah*", announce kings, announce the start of the Holy Days, etc.
The angels are not blowing the ram's horn type or *shofars*.

We see all these things in the Book of Revelation and it is one of the big keys to understanding that scroll.

Because few mainstream Christians kept or learned about the Holy Days of their God, and they adopted the holy days of the fallen angels (pagan holy days), they have been blind to how the book of Revelations is laid out and what and when things happen.

Because they do not follow the Law of their God, they do not understand the difference between shofars and silver trumpets, and when God commands they be used.

I hope this helps and brings some clarity.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).